# Issue with LINQ group by with count

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to run the following query but for some reason `MemberTransactionCount` and `NonMemberTransactionCount` are coming back as the exact same values.  It seems that the `.Where()` clauses aren't working as we'd expect them to.

Hoping someone can point out where I might be going wrong.

```
from trans in transactions
orderby trans.TransactionDate.Year , trans.TransactionDate.Month
group trans by new {trans.TransactionDate.Year, trans.TransactionDate.Month}
into grp
select new MemberTransactions
{
    Month = string.Format("{0}/{1}", grp.Key.Month, grp.Key.Year),
    MemberTransactionCount =
        grp.Where(x => x.Account.Id != Guid.Empty || x.CardNumber != null)
           .Sum(x => x.AmountSpent),
    NonMemberTransactionCount =
        grp.Where(x => x.Account.Id == Guid.Empty && x.CardNumber == null)
           .Sum(x => x.AmountSpent)
}
```

**EDIT**
I've verified in the database that the results are not what they should be.  It seems to be **adding** everything together and not taking into account the `Account` criteria that we're looking at.

Comment: Do you have any data where both of guid and cardnumber is null?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - Yeah, we do.  It depends when the transaction was processed.

Comment: Maybe the data such that we obtain same result.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan We verified in the database that the data should be substantially different.  It seems to be adding everything together instead of taking the `.Where()` into effect.

Comment: I cannot see the surrounding code therefore I can only guess. Could you be fighting with LINQ's **deferred execution** here? See this article, for example: [Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: Change `select new MemberTransactions` to `select new`, `.Sum(x => x.AmountSpent),` to `,` and see what items you get in the two `xTransactionCount` properties - that'll help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with two separate queries.  It's not exactly as I wanted, but it does the job and seems to just as quick as I would have hoped.

```
var memberTrans = from trans in transactions
              where trans.Account != null
                    || trans.CardNumber != null
              orderby trans.TransactionDate.Month
              group trans by trans.TransactionDate.Month
              into grp
              select new
                  {
                      Month = grp.Key,
                      Amount = grp.Sum(x => x.AmountSpent)
                  };
var nonMemberTrans = (from trans in transactions
                  where trans.Account == null
                        && trans.CardNumber == null
                  group trans by trans.TransactionDate.Month
                  into grp
                  select new
                      {
                          Month = grp.Key,
                          Amount = grp.Sum(x => x.AmountSpent)
                      }).ToList();

var memberTransactions = new List<MemberTransactions>();
foreach (var trans in memberTrans)
{
var non = (from nt in nonMemberTrans
           where nt.Month == trans.Month
           select nt).FirstOrDefault();

var date = new DateTime(2012, trans.Month, 1);
memberTransactions.Add(new MemberTransactions
    {
        Month = date.ToString("MMM"),
        MemberTransactionCount = trans.Amount,
        NonMemberTransactionCount = non != null ? non.Amount : 0.00m
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that you doubt the result, though it might be correct.

Add another property for verification:

```
TotalAmount = grp.Sum(x => x.AmountSpent)
```